# How to pass the Parameters to custom action method in wix

Tags: wix, parameter-passing, custom-action, wix3.6

I am new to create MSI installer using wix tool,here i have a query please help me how to resolve this .
  My query is : **I have create a custom UI , in this i have a combo box control and i have bind the combo box values as dynamically using custom Action method it's working fine . Now, i want pass the parameters(combo box selected value) to custom action method,i don't know how to pass parameters .I goggled  but i did not get answer please help me.**

Here is my code

```
 <Binary Id="CustomActions" SourceFile="D:\WIX Projects\ExampleSetup\CustomAction1\bin\Debug\CustomAction1.CA.dll" />
<CustomAction Id='Action1' BinaryKey='CustomActions' DllEntry='FillServerInstances' Execute='immediate' Return='check' />
<UI>
  <Dialog Id="CustomWelcomeEulaDlg" Width="600" Height="450" Title="!(loc.WelcomeEulaDlg_Title)">
    <Control Id="Bitmap" Type="Bitmap" X="0" Y="44" Width="600" Height="380" TabSkip="no" Text="MainImage" />
    <Control Id="Next" Type="PushButton" X="290" Y="430" Width="60" Height="17" Default="yes" Text="Next">
      <Publish Event="DoAction" Value="Action1">1</Publish>
      <Publish Event="NewDialog" Value="LicenseAgreementDlgs"><![CDATA[1]]></Publish>
      <Publish Event="ReinstallMode" Value="ecmus"><![CDATA[Installed = 1]]></Publish>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="Cancel" Type="PushButton" X="350" Y="430" Width="56" Height="17" Cancel="yes" Text="Cancel">
      <Publish Event="SpawnDialog" Value="CancelDlg">1</Publish>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="Title" Type="Text" X="15" Y="6" Width="300" Height="15" Transparent="yes" NoPrefix="yes">
      <Text>[DlgTitleFont]Welcome to the [ProductName] [Wizard]</Text>
    </Control>
    <Control Id="BannerLine" Type="Line" X="0" Y="44" Width="600" Height="0" />
   </Dialog>
```

**Latest Code**

```
 <Product Id="22d32870-651b-4eee-a622-27b2daaade8c" Name="Small Business" Language="1033" Version="1.0.0.0" Manufacturer="Small Business Manufacturing" UpgradeCode="01b2dc2f-61f3-4ff0-a0ba-94dd4cb0829d">

      <Package InstallerVersion="200" Compressed="yes" />

      <Property Id="MSIFASTINSTALL" Value="3" />
        <Binary Id="BIN_CustomAction" SourceFile="D:\WIX Projects\ExampleSetup\CustomAction1\bin\Debug\CustomAction1.CA.dll"/>
        <Binary Id="myAction" SourceFile="D:\WIX Projects\ExampleSetup\CustomAction1\bin\Debug\CustomAction1.CA.dll"/>
       <UIRef Id="WixUI_CustomMinimal" />

        <Media Id="1" Cabinet="media1.cab" EmbedCab="yes" />
         <Property Id="FILEPATH" />
                 <Directory Id="TARGETDIR" Name="SourceDir">
                 <Directory Id="ProgramFilesFolder">
                 <Directory Id="INSTALLLOCATION" Name="Small Business Manufacturing">
                   <Component Id="Component" Guid="af10d5b4-5d25-474f-8360-13b6c0cd7a53">
                    <File Id="Component" Source="D:\WIX Projects\Small Business Manufacturing\Small Business Manufacturing\bin\Debug\Myproject.exe" Compressed="yes" KeyPath="yes" Checksum="yes" />
                    </Component>

             </Directory>
             </Directory>
            </Directory>

                 <Feature Id="ProductFeature" Title="Installation Target" Level="1">
               <ComponentRef Id="Component" />
                </Feature>
                   <InstallExecuteSequence>
                  <Custom Action="myActionId" After="InstallFinalize"></Custom>
                  </InstallExecuteSequence>
              <CustomAction Id="SetCustomActionDataValue" Return="check" Property="myActionId" Value="AnotherValue=[Sqlinstaces]" />
        <UI>
          <ProgressText Action="RunEXE">Configuring Foo... (this may take a few minutes).</ProgressText>
        </UI>

      </Product>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I am aware you can't pass parameters to custom actions. You can set a property in Wix and use `WcaGetProperty` to access that.

I use a listbox which is similar like so:

```
<!--This will be populated via the custom action-->
    <Control Id="ListBoxID" Type="ListBox" Property="COMPORT" Width="80" Height="40" X="80" Y="165" Indirect="no">
      <ListBox Property="COMPORT">
      </ListBox>
    </Control>
```

And in my C++ Custom Action:

```
hr = WcaGetFormattedProperty(L"COMPORT",&szComport);
ExitOnFailure(hr, "failed to get Com Port");
```

EDIT:

Ok so I am assuming your ComboBox is something like this:

```
  <Control Id="DummyComboBox" Hidden="yes" Type="ComboBox" Sorted="yes" ComboList="yes" Property="DUMMYPROPERTY" X="65" Y="60" Width="150" Height="18">
  <ComboBox Property="DUMMYPROPERTY">
  </ComboBox>
```

Make sure your property is is defined like so(ensure capital letters):

```
    <Property Id="DUMMYPROPERTY" Secure="yes"></Property>
```

You do not need a custom action to send the value of the property. All you have to do is use:

```
LPWSTR dummyText = NULL;

hr = WcaGetProperty(L"DUMMYPROPERTY", &dummyText);
ExitOnFailure(hr, "failed to get Dummy Text");
```

That is for a C++ Custom Action not sure what you are using but a quick google search would tell you the relevant code to use.

Comment: Hi thank you for your response.i have try with your coding,i am getting the values in custom method that is only hard coded values.If i give the property value like value="var=[Property]" but it doesn't get the values.

Comment: The property has to be in capital letters `Property="COMPORT"`, please post the code and I will look at it..:)

Comment: I have uploaded my code as latest code please check it once. In this i have pass the value  like                                 <CustomAction Id="SetCustomActionDataValue" Return="check" Property="myActionId" Value="AnotherValue=[Sqlinstaces]" />

Comment: OK, let me get this right. You have filled the box from a custom action from a dll? and you now want another custom action to run after which gets the option that was chosen? Also the second custom action, is this immediate or deferred?

Comment: yes u r right..And i want pass the parameter after choose the option from list box....it is better to me, if it is immediate..

Comment: I have updated my answer, Please let me know if you want me to explain anything else.

Comment: Hi natlie ,i am unable to un-install project if i pass the parameters.Without parameters i m able to uninstall the project,an you give me any idea why it;s not uninstall please........

Comment: Sure I would be happy to help. Do you need to pass the parameters for uninstall? If not you could schedule the custom action to only run on install. I do that with alot of my custom actions that are not needed for uninstall. Or if you want I could take a look at your uninstall verbose log to see if I can spot anything.

Comment: Thanks again ..I solved that problem for now..But,i face a big problem  in my project that is processing status not showing while install my exe files.

Comment: Have you added: `<Control Id="ActionText" Type="Text" X="70" Y="100" Width="285" Height="10">
          <Subscribe Event="ActionText" Attribute="Text" />
        </Control>`

Comment: yes i added but i showing Text Gathering information after that it showing Empty .